# How does Water style function in naruto?

Tags: naruto

So i get that with fire and lightning style you generally create a flame or electric current by turning the chakra into energy and with wind style you breathe in air but how does chakra create earth and water for those styles? we see that some use water that they drink much like gamatatsu and other jutsu depend on water near you but what about the shinobi who just spit out massive amounts of water without having any around or without being able to store it inside of them by drinking? is it like summoning from somewhere else or is it more along the lines of creating actual mass out of nothing?

Answer (score 2):

In the Naruto-verse, chakra can be converted into all forms of nature. That's the logic of the Anime. A user with affinity to any chakra nature can create that element using his/her chakra. Water release is no exception. Ninja's with an affinity to water nature type can use their chakra to create water. However, the amount of water they create depends on how much chakra they have.

Comment: Its not like they are summoning water from an ocean or anything. Its more like the chakra inside the user is being converted into the element. IF your still not getting what i mean then i'd recommend you to read this: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra

Comment: omg i love you! thanks for the explaination it really helped because its so counter intuitive to me but i get it now :) its really cool

Comment: I had the exact same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question.

It's the same as fire/lightning style.You just convert your chakra to water.It's a pretty simple concept,isn't it?There's no summoning involved.It just depends on the fighting style you are accustomed to.Some shinobi are good at the water style.

Comment: but fire and lightning are not physical objects like water or earth, both are a state of energy right? electricity isnt a physical material and neither is fire. so by heating up your chakra (energy) you can make it burn (thereby spending that energy) but you cant create mass from energy can you? creating a charge or a fire from energy both make sense (chakra is energy right?) those seem quite realistic changes in chakra nature but when it comes to earth and water i dont understand how they create physical water or earth from spiritual energy

Comment: @Suitonlover I get what's confusing you, your probably thinking about it in terms of the laws of thermodynamics (which states that energy/matter can neither be created nor destroyed) but then think about it this way. Chakra is energy which can be converted into any form of matter depending on the users nature type.